# How to tackle this guessing game question in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am having a little bit of a hard time with this code.

The directions are:

> Write a loop to populate user_guesses with num_guesses integers. Read integers using int(input()). Ex: If num_guesses is 3 and user enters 9 5 2, then user_guesses is [9, 5, 2].

My first code was:

```
    num_guesses = 3
    user_guesses = []

    for i in user_guesses:
        num_guesses(int(input()))

    print(user_guesses)
```

I've also tried:

```
    num_guesses = 3
    user_guesses = [9,5.2]

    for i in user_guesses:
        num_guesses.join(user_guesses)

    print(user_guesses)
```

Comment: You may find that the best way to tackle these problems is to plan them out on paper first. If you have a variable of `num_guesses = 3` then you know that something needs to be done three times (get user input) and that you don't have any input yet. So, there is no array to iterate over - you need a plain `for` loop to be run three times. Then, inside the loop, you know you want to get input (the problem statement tells you how to do that) and then add the received value to an array (that can be searched for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not iterating over the right things. For example, `user_guesses` is empty in the first example and in the second you're not exactly doing what you claim.

Consider if `num_guesses = 3` then you'd need something more like this:

```
for i in range(num_guesses):
    ...
```

In that loop you'd take the input and add the numbers into a list.

Comment: I took your advice, but It complained and gave empty brackets... but more than one, which is weird....  Something like....           for i in range(num_guesses):
                                                                            i= input(user_guesses)

Comment: or something like    print (arr[i], end=" ")? Although it doesn't input the correct integers...

Comment: OK, take a moment and think about what that's doing. `i` is coming from the range; assigning it a value is not what you need to be doing. You need to add the input into the list; the result of  something like `int(input("Enter a number: "))`. Not sure why you're passing the list into `input`. @Lauren

Comment: Ok. I appreicate the time for explaining it. I was only asking because it was pre-formatted, and it's expected output is [9,5,2] then adding 3 into the mix. and asking to read the integers like said in the directions by int(input()). If I wish I could attach a image, I would show what it looks like.

Comment: ** I wish I could attach a image, I would show what it was looking for. Sorry typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have backwards is that num_guesses isn't taking the input from the user, but user_guesses is. From there you would use the append method to populate the list with the user's inputs

It should look something like this:

```
for i in range(num_guesses):          #iterate over the number of guesses (3 times)
    user_guesses.append(int(input())) #populate the user_guesses list with the input method while converting it to an integer
```